# Conditionals in lstlistings

Tags: listings, conditionals

I am trying to put in some lines of code using the lstlistings-package but the code differs on conditionals. How can I only change some lines depending on the conditional?

Assume I have the If: `\newif\ifshell`. If it is true there should be the following code in a lst-environment:

```
pdprint -l
```

and a few other lines (which are the same for both, true and false).

If `\shell` is false, there should be `pdfprintsvr -l` and the other lines instead.

How can I include the conditional *inside* the lst-environment?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an escape character.

In the following example I've choosen `%` (in this case it has to be escaped because it has a special meaning). You can choose the one you prefer, namely one you don't use inside the `lstlisting` environment.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\newif\ifshell

\section{Shell=true}

\shelltrue
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={\%}{\%}]
%\ifshell%
pdprint -l
%\else%
pdfprintsvr -l
%\fi%
\end{lstlisting}

\section{Shell=false}

\shellfalse
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={\%}{\%}]
%\ifshell%
pdprint -l
%\else%
pdfprintsvr -l
%\fi%
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image]